# How to solve following Error in Java related to user defined methods & objects?

Tags: java, oop, return, user-defined-functions, return-type

I have written following Java code:

```
public class Point2D{
    private double xc, yc;
    
    public Point2D(double x, double y){
            this.xc = x;
            this.yc = y;
        }

    public Point2D createNewPoint(int xOff, int yOff){
        this.xc = xc + xOff;
        this.yc = yc + yOff;
        return xc;  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point2D p1 = new Point2D(2.5, 3.5);

        Point2D p3 = p1.createNewPoint(5, -2);
        System.out.println(p3);
    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Point2D.java:27: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Point2D
        return xc;  
               ^
1 error
```

Can someone help me out to solve this error and also how to return two variables/values from a user-defined method in Java?

Comment: If the method is supposed to create a new instance of Point2D, simply call the Point2D constructor with the appropriate parameters and return the object it creates. What you are doing now is return just one of its fields, the x coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the return value should match the return type. You have returned `xc` which is of type, `double` but the return type is `Point2D`.

Replace

```
public Point2D createNewPoint(int xOff, int yOff){
    this.xc = xc + xOff;
    this.yc = yc + yOff;
    return xc;  
}
```

with

```
public Point2D createNewPoint(int xOff, int yOff) {
    return new Point2D(xc + xOff, yc + yOff);  
}
```

Also, create a `toString` implementation something as shown below so that you can get a meaningful output when you print an object of `Point2D`.

```
public class Point2D {
    private double xc, yc;

    public Point2D(double x, double y) {
        this.xc = x;
        this.yc = y;
    }

    public Point2D createNewPoint(int xOff, int yOff) {
        return new Point2D(xc + xOff, yc + yOff);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point2D [xc=" + xc + ", yc=" + yc + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point2D p1 = new Point2D(2.5, 3.5);

        Point2D p3 = p1.createNewPoint(5, -2);
        System.out.println(p3);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has the side effect of modifying the current `Point2D`, which I assume is not what is desired. What should be done is using `xc + xOff`and `yc + yOff` as the parameters of the constructor, without assigning them to the current `Point2D` instance.

Comment: I did that! But, it returns address of the object ```Point2D``` I want to return values of  parameter ```xc, yc```

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper - Thank you. I agree with your comment and I've updated the answer as well. In fact, originally I was going to post the same thing which I've posted as the update but I then I thought that it's another problem which the OP would resolve after debugging.

Comment: @MukulChikhalkar You can access those values by calling the corresponding getters

Comment: Using both the above codes I am getting output like that: ```com.app.geometry.Point2D@4aa298b7```

Comment: I forgot to mention ```com.app.geometry``` is my Package name!

Comment: @MukulChikhalkar - You need to provide an implementation of `toString` as shown in the answer. The package doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: That worked absolutely fine for me! Thank you very much for your kind help! @ArvindKumarAvinash

Answer (score 1):

1. Add getters for the private fields
2. Return a new object, as shown in the solution below, from createNewPoint method if you want a new object
3. Use the getter methods to access the individual values.

   ```
    class Point2D {
    private double xc, yc;

    public Point2D(double x, double y){
            this.xc = x;
            this.yc = y;
        }

    public Point2D createNewPoint(int xOff, int yOff){
        return new Point2D(this.xc + xOff, this.yc + yOff);  
    }

    public double getXc() {
        return xc;
    }

    public double getYc() {
        return yc;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point2D p1 = new Point2D(2.5, 3.5);

        Point2D p3 = p1.createNewPoint(5, -2);
        System.out.println (p3.getXc() + ":" + p3.getYc());
    }
   ```

   }